# Cannot reuse textfields in JavaFX UI

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote the program that is supposed to allow the user to pick a shape, color, and stroke color and create it in a draw area. Everything works but the only issue is that when I make a circle, press reset, create a rectangle, then if I reset and try to make the circle again, it doesn't let me enter anything in the text fields. If I make a circle, reset, make a rectangle, reset, make an ellipse, reset, I can't use the text fields for circle AND rectangle.

So it seems like I can keep making a shape until I make another shape, then the shape prior to that is unusable.

I suspect it's my reset button, but I'm clearing everything in it, so I don't know what else I can do. Any help is appreciated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;

//@author Luka
public class more4 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //GRIDPANE
        GridPane root = new GridPane();//this will contain all of the flowpanes
        root.setVgap(2.0);//set a vgap to space out the flowpanes inside

        //FLOWPANES TO ENCAPSULATE EACH GROUP OF LABELS AND THEIR RBUTTONS IN.
        FlowPane fp = new FlowPane();
        FlowPane fp2 = new FlowPane();
        FlowPane fp2h = new FlowPane();
        FlowPane fp3 = new FlowPane();
        FlowPane fp4 = new FlowPane();
        FlowPane fp5 = new FlowPane();
        FlowPane cir = new FlowPane();//this flowpane contains the text fields for circle
        FlowPane rec = new FlowPane();//this flowpane contains the text fields for rectangle
        FlowPane ell = new FlowPane();//this flowpane contains the text fields for ellipse
        FlowPane pol = new FlowPane();//this flowpane contains the text fields for polygon

        //LABELS
        Label shape = new Label("Shape: ");
        Label fill = new Label("Fill Color: ");
        Label line = new Label("Line Color: ");
        Label dimensions = new Label("CLICK RESET TO BEGIN!");
        Label drawLabel = new Label("Drawing Area: ");

        //RADIO BUTTONS
        //GROUP ONE:
        final ToggleGroup group1 = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton circle = new RadioButton("Circle");
        circle.setToggleGroup(group1);//add to group1
        circle.setSelected(true);//in this group the circle is selected by default

        RadioButton rectangle = new RadioButton("Rectangle");
        rectangle.setToggleGroup(group1);//add to group1

        RadioButton elipse = new RadioButton("Ellipse");
        elipse.setToggleGroup(group1);//add to group1

        RadioButton polygon = new RadioButton("Polygon");
        polygon.setToggleGroup(group1);//add to group1

        //GROUP TWO:
        final ToggleGroup group2 = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton red = new RadioButton("Red");
        red.setToggleGroup(group2);//add to group2
        red.setSelected(true);//in this group, red is the default selected option

        RadioButton green = new RadioButton("Green");
        green.setToggleGroup(group2);//add to group2

        RadioButton blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
        blue.setToggleGroup(group2);//add to group2

        //GROUP THREE
        final ToggleGroup group3 = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton red2 = new RadioButton("Red");
        red2.setToggleGroup(group3);//add to group3
        red2.setSelected(true);//in this group the red option is the default option

        RadioButton green2 = new RadioButton("Green");
        green2.setToggleGroup(group3);//add to group3

        RadioButton blue2 = new RadioButton("Blue");
        blue2.setToggleGroup(group3);//add to group3

        //TEXTFIELD
        TextField tf = new TextField();//default textfield

        //TEXTFIELDS FOR CIRCLE
        TextField centerX = new TextField();
        centerX.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField centerY = new TextField();
        centerY.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField radius = new TextField();
        radius.setPrefWidth(30.0);

        //TEXTFIELDS FOR RECTANGLE
        TextField setX = new TextField();
        setX.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField setY = new TextField();
        setY.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField setWidth = new TextField();
        setWidth.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField setHeight = new TextField();
        setHeight.setPrefWidth(30.0);

        //TEXTFIELDS FOR ELLIPSE
        TextField setCenterX = new TextField();
        setCenterX.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField setCenterY = new TextField();
        setCenterY.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField setRadiusX = new TextField();
        setRadiusX.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField setRadiusY = new TextField();
        setRadiusY.setPrefWidth(30.0);

        //TEXTFIELD FOR POLYGON
        TextField p1 = new TextField();
        p1.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField p2 = new TextField();
        p2.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField p3 = new TextField();
        p3.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField p4 = new TextField();
        p4.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField p5 = new TextField();
        p5.setPrefWidth(30.0);
        TextField p6 = new TextField();
        p6.setPrefWidth(30.0);

        //PANE - DRAWING AREA
        Pane canvas = new Pane();
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;\n"
                + "-fx-border-insets: 5;\n"
                + "-fx-border-width: 3;\n"
                + "-fx-border-style: dotted;\n");
        canvas.setPrefSize(450, 460);

        ////////////////////////
        cir.getChildren().addAll(centerX, centerY, radius);
        GridPane.setConstraints(cir, 2, 18);
        rec.getChildren().addAll(setX, setY, setWidth, setHeight);
        GridPane.setConstraints(rec, 2, 18);
        ell.getChildren().addAll(setCenterX, setCenterY, setRadiusX, setRadiusY);
        GridPane.setConstraints(rec, 2, 18);
        pol.getChildren().addAll(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
        GridPane.setConstraints(pol, 2, 18);

        //BUTTONS
        Button reset = new Button();
        reset.setText("Reset");
        reset.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                circle.setSelected(true);
                red.setSelected(true);
                red2.setSelected(true);
                canvas.getChildren().clear();
                cir.getChildren().clear();
                centerX.clear();
                centerY.clear();
                radius.clear();
                rec.getChildren().clear();
                ell.getChildren().clear();
                pol.getChildren().clear();
                dimensions.setText("Enter Center X, Center Y, and Radius: ");
                centerX.setPromptText("X");
                centerY.setPromptText("Y");
                radius.setPromptText("R");
                cir.getChildren().addAll(dimensions, centerX, centerY, radius);
                GridPane.setConstraints(cir, 1, 18);
                root.getChildren().addAll(cir);
            }
        });

        //EXIT BUTTON
        Button exit = new Button();
        exit.setText("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Button draw = new Button();
        draw.setText("Draw");
        draw.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                if (circle.isSelected()) {
                    double cx = Double.parseDouble(centerX.getText());
                    double cy = Double.parseDouble(centerY.getText());
                    double rc = Double.parseDouble(radius.getText());
                    Circle c = new Circle();
                    c.setCenterX(cx);
                    c.setCenterY(cy);
                    c.setRadius(rc);
                    canvas.getChildren().add(c);
                    if (red.isSelected()) {
                        c.setFill(Color.RED);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (green.isSelected()) {
                        c.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (blue.isSelected()) {
                        c.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            c.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (rectangle.isSelected()) {
                    double rx = Double.parseDouble(setX.getText());
                    double ry = Double.parseDouble(setY.getText());
                    double rw = Double.parseDouble(setWidth.getText());
                    double rh = Double.parseDouble(setHeight.getText());
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    r.setX(rx);
                    r.setY(ry);
                    r.setWidth(rw);
                    r.setHeight(rh);
                    canvas.getChildren().add(r);
                    if (red.isSelected()) {
                        r.setFill(Color.RED);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (green.isSelected()) {
                        r.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (blue.isSelected()) {
                        r.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            r.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (elipse.isSelected()) {
                    double ex = Double.parseDouble(setCenterX.getText());
                    double ey = Double.parseDouble(setCenterY.getText());
                    double erx = Double.parseDouble(setRadiusX.getText());
                    double ery = Double.parseDouble(setRadiusY.getText());
                    Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
                    e.setCenterX(ex);
                    e.setCenterY(ey);
                    e.setRadiusX(erx);
                    e.setRadiusY(ery);
                    canvas.getChildren().add(e);
                    if (red.isSelected()) {
                        e.setFill(Color.RED);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (green.isSelected()) {
                        e.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (blue.isSelected()) {
                        e.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            e.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (polygon.isSelected()) {
                    double po = Double.parseDouble(p1.getText());
                    double pt = Double.parseDouble(p2.getText());
                    double ph = Double.parseDouble(p3.getText());
                    double pf = Double.parseDouble(p4.getText());
                    double pi = Double.parseDouble(p5.getText());
                    double ps = Double.parseDouble(p6.getText());
                    Polygon p = new Polygon();
                    p.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                        po, pt,
                        ph, pf,
                        pi, ps
                    });
                    canvas.getChildren().add(p);
                    if (red.isSelected()) {
                        p.setFill(Color.RED);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (green.isSelected()) {
                        p.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else if (blue.isSelected()) {
                        p.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                        if (red2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.RED);
                        } else if (green2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (blue2.isSelected()) {
                            p.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        circle.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if (circle.isSelected()) {
                    final Label dimensions = new Label("Enter radius: ");
                    GridPane.setConstraints(dimensions, 1, 4);
                }
            }
        });

        circle.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (circle.isSelected()) {
                rec.getChildren().clear();
                ell.getChildren().clear();
                pol.getChildren().clear();
                dimensions.setText("Enter Center X, Center Y, and Radius: ");
                centerX.setPromptText("X");
                centerY.setPromptText("Y");
                radius.setPromptText("R");
                cir.getChildren().addAll(dimensions, centerX, centerY, radius);
                GridPane.setConstraints(cir, 1, 18);
                root.getChildren().addAll(cir);
            }
        });
        rectangle.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (rectangle.isSelected()) {
                cir.getChildren().clear();
                ell.getChildren().clear();
                pol.getChildren().clear();
                dimensions.setText("Enter X and Y coordinates, length, width: ");
                setX.setPromptText("X");
                setY.setPromptText("Y");
                setWidth.setPromptText("W");
                setHeight.setPromptText("L");
                rec.getChildren().addAll(dimensions, setX, setY, setWidth, setHeight);
                GridPane.setConstraints(rec, 1, 18);
                root.getChildren().addAll(rec);
            }
        });
        elipse.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (elipse.isSelected()) {
                cir.getChildren().clear();
                rec.getChildren().clear();
                pol.getChildren().clear();
                dimensions.setText("Enter Center X and Y, and Radius X and Y: ");
                setCenterX.setPromptText("X");
                setCenterY.setPromptText("Y");
                setRadiusX.setPromptText("X");
                setRadiusY.setPromptText("Y");
                ell.getChildren().addAll(dimensions, setCenterX, setCenterY, setRadiusX, setRadiusY);
                GridPane.setConstraints(ell, 1, 18);
                root.getChildren().addAll(ell);
            }
        });
        polygon.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (polygon.isSelected()) {
                cir.getChildren().clear();
                rec.getChildren().clear();
                ell.getChildren().clear();
                dimensions.setText("Enter six points: ");
                p1.setPromptText("P1");
                p2.setPromptText("P2");
                p3.setPromptText("P3");
                p4.setPromptText("P4");
                p5.setPromptText("P5");
                p6.setPromptText("P6");
                pol.getChildren().addAll(dimensions, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
                GridPane.setConstraints(pol, 1, 18);
                root.getChildren().addAll(pol);
            }
        });

        //GRIDPANE ADD CHILDREN
        root.getChildren().addAll(fp, fp2, fp2h, fp3, fp4, fp5);

        //ADDING CHILDREN TO THE FLOWPANES AND SETTING THE FLOWPANES' POSITION
        fp.getChildren().addAll(shape, circle, rectangle, elipse, polygon);
        GridPane.setConstraints(fp, 1, 1);
        fp2.getChildren().addAll(fill, red, green, blue);
        GridPane.setConstraints(fp2, 1, 6);
        fp2h.getChildren().addAll(line, red2, green2, blue2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(fp2h, 1, 12);
        fp3.getChildren().addAll(dimensions);
        GridPane.setConstraints(fp3, 1, 18);
        fp4.getChildren().addAll(drawLabel, canvas);
        GridPane.setConstraints(fp4, 1, 24);
        fp5.getChildren().addAll(reset, exit, draw);
        GridPane.setConstraints(fp5, 1, 30);
        fp5.setHgap(138.0);

        //SCENE
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Lab 4");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code and post a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal*). You cannot possibly need all of this to demonstrate the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you notice any exceptions when running your code? In your action handlers you are constantly adding the same nodes to the scene graph and this is not allowed. For example in your reset handler:

```
                root.getChildren().addAll(cir);
```

After the first call "cir" is already in the scene graph and you can't add it a second time.